# iphone Ad Hoc Distribution no appearing in itunes

Tags: iphone, itunes, distribution

I have found a problem trying to install an ad hoc distribution on my itunes.
1) I have distribution certificate
2) I have distribution profile
3) I have add entitlements.plist, although from what I read this is no longer required.  it looks like the plist does not even have a get-task-allow bool anymore to set.  I have tried with adding this and leaving it, as well as no entitlments.plist

After compiling (which goes off without a hitch), I drag the application to my itunes.  It looks like it works (although no loading time), and asks if I want to replace a mobileprovision file that already exists (if I do it multiple times).

The App icon never appears in itunes, syncing does nothing.  Its as if it isn't getting copied, but there isn't an error message to tell me what i'm doing wrong.  This was working last month with a different app.  I do not understand why it isn't working now...

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0):

If you are running iOS 4, you can use over-the-air distribution to install an AdHoc build directly from Mobile Safari.  This is a little painful to setup the first time, but removes the hassle of having to mess with iTunes from the process.

http://jeffreysambells.com/posts/2010/06/22/ios-wireless-app-distribution/